# Python NRF24 convert Payload

Tags: python, arduino

since some days I try to connect an Arduino with a Raspberry by an NRF24 module.
By the examples i got some working code in C (@raspberry) but I want to use python due to the web app.

The problem is I can't interpret the msq send by the Arduino. The Arduino should send 8 times `uint32_t` in one payload. After receive in Raspberry I got 8 times 4 `uint8_t`.

Arduino MSG:

```
uint32_t SendMsg[8] = {222, micros(), 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};
```

Raspberry RCV:

```
Received: [222, 0, 0, 0, 24, 22, 97, 210, 10, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0]
```

The Raspberry "destroy" the int32 to 4 times int8 ... how I may combine them again?

The RCV is a list of int.

Here the complete code:
**Raspberry:**

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from lib_nrf24 import NRF24
import time
import spidev

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pipes = [0xAB, 0xCD, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0x71]

radio = NRF24(GPIO, spidev.SpiDev())
radio.begin(0, 22)

radio.setPayloadSize(32)
radio.setChannel(77)
radio.setDataRate(NRF24.BR_1MBPS)
radio.setPALevel(NRF24.PA_MIN)

radio.setAutoAck(True)
radio.enableDynamicPayloads()
radio.enableAckPayload()

radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes)
radio.printDetails()
radio.startListening()

while(1):
    # ackPL = [1]
    while not radio.available(0):
        time.sleep(1 / 100)
    receivedMessage = []
    radio.read(receivedMessage, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())

    print("Received: {}".format(receivedMessage))
```

**Arduino**

```cpp
//Send.ino

#include<SPI.h>
#include<RF24.h>

// ce, csn pins
RF24 radio(6, 10);


uint32_t RcvMsg[8] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};


void setup(void){
  radio.begin();
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
  radio.setChannel(77);
  radio.openWritingPipe(0xABCDABCD71LL);
  radio.enableDynamicPayloads();
  radio.powerUp();

}

void loop(void){
    const char text[] = "Hello World is awe DOAs";
     uint32_t SendMessage;
     uint32_t SendMsg[8] = {222, micros(), 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};



  radio.write(&SendMsg, sizeof(SendMsg));

  if ( radio.isAckPayloadAvailable() ) {
              radio.read(&RcvMsg, sizeof(RcvMsg));
  }
              Serial.print(" SendMsg[0]: ");Serial.print(SendMsg[0]); Serial.print(" SendMsg[1]: ");Serial.print(SendMsg[1]); Serial.print(" SendMsg[2]: ");Serial.print(SendMsg[2]); Serial.print(" SendMsg[3]: ");Serial.print(SendMsg[3]); Serial.print(" SendMsg[4]: ");Serial.print(SendMsg[4]);Serial.print(" SendMsg[5]: ");Serial.print(SendMsg[5]);Serial.print(" SendMsg[6]: ");Serial.print(SendMsg[6]); Serial.print(" SendMsg[7]: ");Serial.println(SendMsg[7]);
              Serial.print(" RcvMsg[0] : ");Serial.print(RcvMsg[0]);Serial.print(" RcvMsg[1] : ");Serial.print(RcvMsg[1]);Serial.print(" RcvMsg[2] : ");Serial.print(RcvMsg[2]);Serial.print(" RcvMsg[3] : ");Serial.print(RcvMsg[3]); Serial.print(" RcvMsg[4] : ");Serial.print(RcvMsg[4]);Serial.print(" RcvMsg[5] : ");Serial.print(RcvMsg[5]);Serial.print(" RcvMsg[6] : ");Serial.print(RcvMsg[6]);Serial.print(" RcvMsg[7] : ");Serial.println(RcvMsg[7]);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
#============================================================================#
#============================================================================#
#   translate radio Msq from byte to int
#============================================================================#
def translate_from_radio(msg, size):
    translated_msg=[]
    for i in range (0, size, 4):
        translated_msg.append(int.from_bytes([msg[i+3], msg[i+2], msg[i+1], msg[i]], byteorder='big')) 

    #print("Translate FROM Radio: " + str(msg) + " --> " + str(translated_msg))
    return translated_msg
#============================================================================#
#============================================================================#
#   Split the msg element in 4 bytes and add it to translated msg
#============================================================================#   
def translate_to_radio(msg):
    translated_msg=[]
    for i in range (0, len(msg)):
        x=msg[i].to_bytes(4, byteorder='big')
        for g in reversed(x):
            translated_msg.append(g)        

    #print("Translate TO Radio: " + str(msg) + " --> " + str(translated_msg))
    return translated_msg
```